# I am trying to stream arabic tweet from an api twitter with python

Tags: python-3.x

```
class listener(StreamListener):
     def on_data(self, data):
         try:
             tweet=data
             t=tweet.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
             print(t)
             saveFile = open('E:\\da.json','a')
             saveFile.write(t)
             saveFile.write('\n')
             saveFile.close()
             return True
         except BaseException as e:
             print ('failed on data',str(e))
             time.sleep(5)

     def on_error(self,status):
         print (status)

         auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
         auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
         twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
         twitterStream.filter(track=['رياضه'],languages=["ar"])
```

The error appears is:

> failed on data 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83d'  in 
>   position 2808: surrogates not allowed and  continues to download the
>   data

how I can solve it can  anyone help me.
the program print the text in Arabic but when load it with the next program.

```
 with io.open('E:\\da.json', 'r',encoding ='utf-8') as f:                          
     line = f.readline()                                                   
     tweets = json.loads(line) 

     print(tweets)
```

The error :

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position
>   111: invalid continuation byte